# How to use Systemd to restart a service when down?

Tags: linux, service, debian, monitor, systemd

On my server I use elasticSearch which regularly goes down and the result is a 500 error for my users. I understand Systemd is now the reference for managing services.

How can I use Systemd to restart my elastic search service automatically when it goes down? I  found ways to restart it, but not automatically without me checking if it's down.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using a systemd service file to start your service, then add the lines below to your service file from where you are starting your service:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=here will be your service executable name
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
```

- `Restart=`

  Configures whether the service shall be restarted when the service process exits, is killed, or a timeout is reached. Takes one of the following values: `no`, `on-success`, `on-failure`, `on-abnormal`, `on-watchdog`, `on-abort` or `always`. If set to `no` (the default).
- `RestartSec=`

  Configures the time to sleep before restarting a service (as configured with `Restart=`). Takes a unit-less value in seconds.

These two options have to be under the `[Service]` tag in a service file.

Comment: can you ellaborate on how to do this when starting from scratch? using apt-get install system-sysv gets me a "Package 'systemd-sysv' has no installation candidate"

Comment: Starting from scratch -- didnt understand...
Linux comes with a system framework component called systemD. Kernel starts this nd once systemD is up, it starts all services on booting of a device. SystemD is a replacement of System V init.


is systemD available in your linux platform.
If yes then this is just few line changes in service file to get it worked.

Comment: nice, I could make that work. I needed to switch from linux 14.04 to 14.10 and then most of useful services already have their unit file under /run/systemd/generator.late

Answer (score 1):

I have used [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) monit for this.  [A post at askfedoraproject](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/44938/can-systemd-replace-monit/) suggests to me that this is still a good way to monitor processes and automatically restart them.

It provides good granular configuration of the monitoring functions, how to decide if a process has failed, and actions to be taken to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

Systemctl - System and Service manager for linux systems

Basics about systemd:
Features:
1.Parallel startup of system service at boot time
2.On demand activation of daemons
3.Dependecy based service control logic

```
* limited support at runlevel
* panic is not support panic command(systemctl no custom commands)
* systemctl can only communicate with services which are started by systemd
* sysd stop only running services
* system services don't inherit any context like HOME or PATH variable
* All services subject to default timeout of 5 minutes can be configured.These prevents from system to freeze in case of some application stop to respond.
```

Systemd units: service , path, mount, snapshot, swap, timer, device etc
Unit Type
File Extension
Description
Service unit
.service
A system service.
Target unit
.target
A group of systemd units.
Automount unit
.automount
A file system automount point.
Device unit
.device
A device file recognized by the kernel.
Mount unit
.mount
A file system mount point.
Path unit
.path
A file or directory in a file system.
Scope unit
.scope
An externally created process.
Slice unit
.slice
A group of hierarchically organized units that manage system processes.
Snapshot unit
.snapshot
A saved state of the systemd manager.
Socket unit
.socket
An inter-process communication socket.
Swap unit
.swap
A swap device or a swap file.
Timer unit
.timer
A systemd timer.

unit file's Filelocation: /etc/systemd/system

Conf file: /etc/systemd/system.conf

Systemd provides a lot of functionallity basically you can control all the resouces of linux system that gives you give a lot of functionality.We are focussing on managing system service in this article.

for more details: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd

MANAGING SYSTEM SERVICES:
systemctl
Description
systemctl start name.service
Starts a service.
systemctl stop name.service
Stops a service.
systemctl restart name.service
Restarts a service.
systemctl try-restart name.service
Restarts a service only if it is running.
systemctl reload name.service
Reloads configuration.
systemctl status name.service
systemctl is-active name.service
Checks if a service is running.
systemctl list-units --type service --all
Displays the status of all services.
systemctl
Description
systemctl enable name.service
Enables a service.
systemctl disable name.service
Disables a service.
systemctl status name.service
systemctl is-enabled name.service
Checks if a service is enabled.
systemctl list-unit-files --type service
Lists all services and checks if they are enabled.
systemctl list-dependencies --after
Lists services that are ordered to start before the specified unit.
systemctl list-dependencies --before
Lists services that are ordered to start after the specified unit.